# how to join 2 tables having equal attributes but different data in each table using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

**Table 1**

```
create table itemType1(
  maincatg varchar(25), 
  subcatg varchar(25), 
  price float(5), 
  primary key(maincatg, subcatg) 
);
```

**Table2**

```
create table itemType2(
     maincatg varchar(25), 
     subcatg varchar(25), 
     price float(5), 
     primary key(maincatg, subcatg) 
);
```

Comment: Why 2 tables? They are the same. Table is like a class or type and it is usually pointless to have two identical classes.

Comment: Unless you are deliberately partitioning your data, you should be better off using just one table with a flag (as another column) added to indicate the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) rather than a `JOIN`.

```
(SELECT maincatg, subcatg, price
FROM itemType1)

UNION ALL

(SELECT maincatg, subcatg, price
FROM itemType2)
```

This is effectively a concatenation of the two tables.

Beyond that, I'm really not sure what you're hoping to accomplish.

Comment: How to put this bunch of data into a single table then?

Comment: Really thnk u for the answer. I just created a view using your anser. Was perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of table is going to be much easier to work with.

```
create table item(
  maincatg varchar(25),
  subcatg varchar(25), 
  price float(5),
  type tinyint(1),
  primary key(maincatg, subcatg) 
);
```

It also looks like you're going to have a lot of duplicate data in your maincatg and subcatg columns. If I was doing it I would have those in another table or possibly two. You join them with ids.

You will probably have an easier time if you read up on database normalization. It's an easy concept to brush up on as long as you find a decent tutorial and there are plenty out there.

If you're stuck using a database that you can't change for whatever reason, you should probably edit your question to say so, or else most answers will probably be similar to mine.

Comment: I have these in seperate tables. But for a adding a seach* option I'm in need of a table( or just a view) having all those data in a single table. So is there any way?